# Проблема с тернарным оператором в Java

Tags: java, if, тернарный-оператор

Нужно записать выражение без if, потому использую тернарный оператор

```
if (dictionary.containsKey(key)) {
      dictionary.put(key, dictionary.get(key) + 1);
    } 
else {
      dictionary.put(key, 1);
}
```

Пишу это так:

```
     (dictionary.containsKey(key)) ? (dictionary.put(key, dictionary.get(key) + 1)) : (dictionary.put(key, 1));
```

И он выдаёт ошибку "Not a statement", как быть?

Comment: dictionary-это LinkedHashMap

Comment: Наверно выражение нужно поместить в тело метода.

Comment: `dictionary.put(key, dictionary.containsKey(key) ? dictionary.get(key) + 1 : 1);`

Comment: @ ArchDemon Сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, стейтмент в тернарном операторе в java недопустим. Альтернативно можно использовать тернарный оператор внутри put:

```
dictionary.put(key, dictionary.containsKey(key) ? dictionary.get(key) + 1 : 1)
```